# background image as responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

if i have this group of divs, how can i change the dimensions of each background image when the browser is resized? Basically put all content of box as responsive design.

So the maximum width is the dimension of the image.

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="dog_1"></div>
  <div class="dog_2"></div>
  <div class="dog_3"></div>  
  <div class="dog_4"></div>
</div>

div[class*='dog_'] {
   background: url("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/419c%2BE2j0kL._SL500_AA300_.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:200px
}
```

demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LPKkk/

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the background-size property:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

However it isn't supported in IE7&8.  If you need to support these browsers, you might have to use image elements with percent based width and height instead of background images or IE's proprietary filter.  Example:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../background.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

One thing about IE image filters is that the image path is relative to the HTML document (like an  element), rather than being relative to the CSS document like a normal background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 `background-size: cover/contain;` property to scale the background image: http://jsfiddle.net/LPKkk/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    -moz-background-size: cover !important;
    -o-background-size: cover !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
```

(I had to use !important for some reason to get the cover to work last time)

Here's a [link to few other approaches too](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).